# how to filter list object by using stream map filter in java

Tags: list, kotlin, java-8, stream, java-stream

i want to filter a list of student in java. I have a student class in kotlin  like this.

```
class Student(
    var id: String? = null,
    var firstName: String? = null,
    var lastName: String? = null
) {

    constructor(entity: StudentCourse?): this() {
        if (entity != null) {
            this.id = entity.id.id
            this.name = entity.name
        }
    }
}

class StudentCourse (@EmbeddedId open var id: StudentCourseId)  {
   
    constructor() : this(StudentCourseId())

    open var name: Boolean? = null
}

@Embeddable
open class StudentCourseId: Serializable {

    open var id: String? = null

    open var deptName: String? = null
}
```

this is the list i want to filter :

```
var students: List<Student> = listOf(
   Student("14adbv45", "dan", "GEG"),
   Student("96adbv42","Bob", "Bowyer"),
   Student("30adbv45","Emily", "Eden")
 )
```

I do this

```
 List<students> studentListContainsFirstNameBob = students.stream()
                        .map(StudentCourse)
                        .filter(e -> e.getFirstName.equals("Bob"))
                        .flatMap(List::stream);
```

but  it doesn't work.

How can i do it please

Comment: Where `name` property that you're using in Student's constructor comes from? `Student` has **no** field `name` as well as `StudentCourse`.

Comment: *`"it doesn't work"`* - that a poor description. Please tell exactly what happening? Don't make us guess, **whenever** you're getting a compilation error (I suspect that's the case here) - *copy-past the message issued by the compiler*, exception - *post the stack-trace*, you're getting incorrect output - *show it*. Use ***edit*** button below the post, or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73732429/edit)

Comment: You can't just put the name of a class as your `map()` argument. You need a lambda or a method reference. But I don't see what converting to StudentCourse would have to do with filtering by name. What were you trying to do with that line of code? Also, the method for checking equality is `equals()` not `equal()`.

Comment: + you don't need to use `stream` in kotlin

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code.
For example in this part:

```
 constructor(entity: StudentCourse?): this() {
        if (entity != null) {
            this.id = entity.id.id
            this.name = entity.name
        }
    }
```

The `entity.name` refers to `StudentCourse#name`, but this property is actually of `Boolean` type, so comparing it to `String` doe snot make much sense. You have also doubled `.id` which is incorrect.

Next thing, I am not sure what this snipped should do, was the intention to link a student with given course? If so, you would probably like to add a list of students to a course, or a list of courses to a student (which sounds more correct).

Finally, when it comes to filtering a list, you can get students with first name Bob in this way:

```
var studentListContainsFirstNameBob: List<Student> = students
        .filter { it.firstName.equals("Bob") }
        .toList()
```

Mind the `it` variable refers to the element from the list, it could also be written:

```
var studentListContainsFirstNameBob: List<Student> = students
        .filter { student -> student.firstName.equals("Bob") }
        .toList()
```